# One-word synonym: 'the same thing'

Tags: synonyms

Please do NOT rephrase or rewrite the sentence.  Only the bolded can be reworded.

> [[1.]](http://www.forgottenbooks.com/readbook_text/Writings_Library_Containing_His_Autobiography_Notes_on_Virginia_v18_1000369408/463) It would be to say that to go to a place, or from a place, means **the same thing**.

Instead, what are some synonyms of the bolded?
Or is it an adverb? Can I rewrite it as:

> 2. It would be to say that to go to a place, or from a place, means **equivalently/identically**.

Footnote: The quote above is from [this essay](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%22means%20the%20same%22&s=1111311111&sa=&r=20&sr=), but beware of this version's many typos.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to figure out? Are you trying to understand the exact meaning of "the same thing" here, or learn more ways to state the same thing, or figure out the syntactical category it falls in, or...?

Comment: @WendiKidd I apologise for any confusion. In answer to your comment, I wish to `learn more ways to state the same thing`, and `figure out the syntactical category`, but not the others. Please feel free to edit my OP.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not an adverb.  It is a noun phrase, which is the direct object of *means*.  So you could not replace it with a one-word adverb; only with a one-word noun.

As for your example sentence, it is a bit disconcerting to try to come up with a word that fits, because going "to a place" and "from a place" are **NOT** the same thing.

Comment: It doesn't say that they're the same thing.